# How to replace the white space after a number with a delimiter in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have a number of different values in a column that all represent customer (see the an example below)

What I'm looking to do is if a space (" ") comes after the customer "number" then replace that space with a ",". Otherwise, don't replace it, as there are some instances where a customer name has a space in it and I'd like to keep that.

Example:

```
data.frame(customer = c("HOSPITAL FUN:12456 HOSPITAL:23456",
                       "MEDICAL GR:78988 MEDICAL ABC:98778 MEDICAL:90808"))
```

I'd like it to look like

```
data.frame(customer = c("HOSPITAL FUN:12456,HOSPITAL:23456",
                       "MEDICAL GR:78988,MEDICAL ABC:98778,MEDICAL:90808"))
```

My thought is that if I could look for a space coming after a number and replace that it would work but I'm not sure what the expression would be. Any help woudl be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Your sample indicates `(?<=\d)[ ](?!")` replace `,` https://regex101.com/r/sp4ZWC/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `gsub` with replacement group `\\1`

```
data.frame(lapply(df, gsub, pattern="(\\d+) ", replacement="\\1,"))
                                          customer
1                HOSPITAL FUN:12456,HOSPITAL:23456
2 MEDICAL GR:78988,MEDICAL ABC:98778,MEDICAL:90808
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dpylr` and `stringr` could be something like this:

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(stringr)
 
 df <- data.frame(customer = c("HOSPITAL FUN:12456 HOSPITAL:23456",
                               "MEDICAL GR:78988 MEDICAL ABC:98778 
                                MEDICAL:90808"))
 
 # Replace space with comma if it comes after a customer number
 df_new <- df %>%
   mutate(customer = str_replace_all(customer, "(\\d)\\s", "\\1,"))
     
#                                               customer
#1                HOSPITAL FUN:12456,HOSPITAL:23456
#2 MEDICAL GR:78988,MEDICAL ABC:98778,MEDICAL:90808
```